# VBA Function Passing Multi Variables back to Sub

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I have a large string over 500 char which is called strEssay. I want to use a function(since I will need to look for several patterns) to return two values if (for example the name) Frank is found or not.

This is the function I'm trying to use:

```
Function NameFinder(strEssay as String, strName as String)

    Dim varNameCounter as Variant
    Dim strNameFinderResult as String

    varNameCounter = 0
    strNameFinderResult = ""

    If strEssay like "*" & strName & "*" Then
       strNameFinderResult = strName
       varNameFinderCounter = 1

    Else
       strNameFinderResult = ""
       varNameFinderCounter = .001

    EndIf

End Function
```

I want to be able to return back to my subroutine both 'strNameFinderResult' and 'varNameFinderCounter'.

Is there any way that I can return both values?

If I can't return both simultaneously can I return one through the function and the other through a textbox or something? What would calling the function look like in the subroutine and/or how would I need to change my function?

Comment: You can return multiple results in an array - eg. `NameFinder = Array(strNameFinderResult, varNameFinderCounter)`   Or create a Type/Class and return an instance of that.

Comment: Can you show me how that would look in the sub? I'm really confused about functions...I've been getting away in the past without really using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameFinder()` function, returning array of 3 elements. It is called and returned by `TestMe()`, writing the following to the console:

[image]

```
Function NameFinder(essay As String, name As String)
    
    Dim nameFinderResult As String
    Dim namefinderCounter As String
    
    nameFinderResult = "" & essay & name
    namefinderCounter = 0.001 + 12
    
    NameFinder = Array(nameFinderResult, namefinderCounter, "something else")

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = NameFinder("foo", "bar")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you have to give the routine a type like this:

```
Function NameFinder(strEssay as String, strName as String) as string
```

But, that returns only ONE value.

So, a function (as opposed to a sub) returns one value (as a general rule).

However, you CAN also return parameters that you pass. I mean, in above, you can't make TWO assignments to one variable, can  you?

So, you can use a Sub like this:

```
Sub NameFinder(strEssay as String, strName as String, _
       strNameFinderResult as string, _
       varNameFinderCounter as double)

If strEssay like "*" & strName & "*" Then
   strNameFinderResult = strName
   varNameFinderCounter = 1

Else
   strNameFinderResult = ""
   varNameFinderCounter = .001

EndIf
```

So in code, you now can go:

```
dim strMyResult      as string
dim strFinderCount   as Double

Call NameFinder("MyEassy", "Joe Blow", strMyResult, strFinderCount)
```

So, you can return values with the parameters.

Now, I suppose it possible for some strange reason, that you want to use a function to return two values with a single assignment?

What you would do is this in your code module.

Define a custom type, and use that.

eg this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Type SearchResult
   strName    As String
   FindCount  As Double
End Type
  
Function NameFinder(strEssay As String, strName As String) As SearchResult

   NameFinder.FindCount  = 0
   NameFinder.strName    = ""

   If strEssay Like "*" & strName & "*" Then
      NameFinder.strName = strName
      NameFinder.FindCount = 1

   Else
      NameFinder.strName = ""
      NameFinder.FindCount = 0.001

   End If

End Function
```

So, now to use in code? You can go like this:

```
dim MyResults as SearchResult

MyResults = NameFinder("My eassy", "Joe Blow")
debug.print "Name found result = " & MyResults.strName
debug.print "Count of find = " & MyResult.FindCount
```

The VERY nice thing about above is you get full intel-sense in your code editor.

eg this:

[image]

So by building a custom data type, you can use "one" assignment for the return type. And you get nice type checking and inteli-sense in the VBA code editor.

And you can even do this:

[image]

But, to get both variables, then you would in theory wind up calling the function two times. So, you can actually use the function without declarer of variables like this:

```
Debug.Print NameFinder("MyEassy", "Joe blow").strName
Debug.Print NameFinder("MyEassy", "Joe blow").FindCount
```

So, I don't recommend the above, but in the case in which you ONLY want one of the return values, then the raw expression (function) like above would be a use case (and no need to even declare a return variable).

But, without a doubt, define a custom type in code as per above. The reason is now you get a really nice VBA editor type-checking, inteli-sense, and also that you only have to declare "one" variable that holds two values.

In fact, the results are very much like JavaScript, or even c# in which you declare a "class" type. So with a custom "type" you are declaring a data type of your own. And the beauty of this is if you need say 3 values, then once again you create a type with 3 "inside" values.

The you ONLY have to declare that one variable as the custom type.
With this you get:

Very valuable compile time syntax and data type checking of the var types you are using.

You get GREAT VBA inteli-sense while coding - which means less coding mistakes.
And you type far less typing in the VBA editor as it will pop-up the choices for you as you write code. And you can't type or choose the wrong sub - type, as the compiler will catch this.

Comment: Thanks Albert! I appreciate your help!